# toHaveBeenCalledWith throws error for my unit test case

Tags: javascript, angular

I am writing a unit test to see the service was called with the correct url. PFB my test case and code.
But I get this error:

```
ContactTriageService › it should get data from ContactInfo endpoint based 
on the url inputted

expect(jest.fn())[.not].toHaveBeenCalledWith()

Matcher error: received value must be a mock or spy function

Received has type:  string
Received has value: "contact-info"
```

// test case

```
it('it should get data from ContactInfo endpoint based on the url inputted', () => {
const url ='contact-info';
const { service, get } = spectator;
const http = get<HttpClient>(HttpClient).get.and.returnValue(of());
service.getserviceResponse(url).subscribe();
expect(http.calls.first().args[0]).toHaveBeenCalledWith(url);
});
```

// service.ts

```
getserviceResponse(url: string): Observable<ContactInfoSelectionResponse|ContactInfoResponse> { 
return this.http.get<any>(url)
}
```

Comment: What version of Angular are you using? Refer to this sample [code](https://stackblitz.com/angular/ngxmayagexp) if you're using the latest Angular version using `HttpClientModule`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
it('should call the contact info endpoint', () => {
const { service, get } = spectator;
const http = get<HttpClient>(HttpClient).get.mockReturnValue(of());

service.getContactInfoData().subscribe();
expect(http.mock.calls[0][0]).toEqual('/contact-info');
});
```